# Best text editor for EE5?

Tags: richtext, ckeditor

I'm looking to build a site in EE5 and was wondering if I could get some text editor recommendations?

I've used WYGWAM with EE2 and enjoyed it.

The rich text editor with EE5 actually seems good, except I can't find a way to upload a file and make a link to it. Would I make my users first upload a file from File Manager, then link to it?

Comment: No doubt. Go for *Wygwam*. It will gives to all the things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RTE with EE5 is OK, but as you observe has some limitations regarding handling of images.

The alternatives are all add-ons that provide a wrapper to some other Rich Text Editor source.

- [Wyvern](https://addons.reinos.nl/wyvern) - A wrapper for [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/)
- [Wygwam](https://eeharbor.com/wygwam) - Also a wrapper for [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/)
- [Editor](https://eeharbor.com/editor) - A wrapper for [Redactor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/)

My personal favourite is Wyvern, but all are good options.

HTH